# wsdl parsing error, failed to load external entity "http://localhost:10088/SoapService/public/testService.php?wsdl"

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to create a web service for Ipad application so that I can sync the data between application and web server please guide me.

I trying to test this simple PHP script to test and create simple web service but I am getting this error, where am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
require_once('Zend/Soap/AutoDiscover.php');
require_once('Zend/Soap/Server.php');
require_once('Zend/Soap/Client.php');
?>
<?php 

class Login {

    /**
     * Add method
     *
     * @param Int $param1
     * @param Int $param2
     * @return Int
     */
    public function math_add($param1, $param2) {
        return $param1+$param2;
    }

    /**
     * Logical not method
     *
     * @param boolean $param1
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function logical_not($param1) {
        return !$param1;
    }

    /**
     * Simple array sort
     *
     * @param Array $array
     * @return Array
     */
    public function simple_sort($array) {
        asort($array);
        return $array;
    }
}

class LoginController
{
    private $_WSDL_URI = "http://localhost:10088/SoapService/public/index.php?wsdl";

    public function init()
    {
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

        $this->hadleWSDL();

        if(isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
            //return the WSDL
            $this->hadleWSDL();
        } else {
            //handle SOAP request
            $this->handleSOAP();
        }
    }

    private function hadleWSDL() {
        $autodiscover = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover();
        $autodiscover->setClass('Login');
        $autodiscover->handle();
    }

    private function handleSOAP() {
        $soap = new Zend_Soap_Server($this->_WSDL_URI);
        $soap->setClass('Login');
        $soap->handle();
    }

    public function clientAction() {
        $client = new Zend_Soap_Client($this->_WSDL_URI);

        echo $client->math_add(11, 55);
        echo $client->logical_not(true);
        echo $client->simple_sort( array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple"));

    }

}

$soapController = new LoginController();
$soapController->init();
$soapController->indexAction();
$soapController->clientAction();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else stumbles over this code, like I did...
I did get this example to work just fine. Initially I had a "wrong version" exception. All you need to change in the code is to add the URL to the Soap Server.

I added `$autodiscover->setUri("http://some/path/to/soapserver/");` and it runs just fine.